# Applying a patch file in a powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate building some dependencies on my Win machine, throught Powershell scripting. I am just fetching sources from Github, building throught CMake etc. For one of the dependencies, I need to apply a patch from a pull request.

In my script, I am creating the `asm.patch` file automatically. This is the correct patch file. If I apply this patch on a Unix environment through `patch < asm.patch`, everything works fine. I have no way of applying this patch file on my Powershell script though.

The thing I tried, I installed GnuWin32 native port of `patch`. In my script, I am calling it like `patch -i asm.patch` because Powershell does not let me to use token `<`. It calls the patch command correctly. But GnuWin32 patch port opens up a dialog related to permissions. So it is not useful for my automation needs.

Question is, what is the standard way of applying `.patch` file on Powershell scripts?

Comment: Have a look at the output of the `Get-Command -Name '*update*' | Where-Object { $_.CommandType -eq 'Function' }` command. Until you have some code in the question, please ask on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

**`git apply` worked eventually**

I was working with a temporary, [generated project](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/kotlin.md) in a git 'ignored' folder.  The patch was oriented to the folder of the temporary project but because of the surrounding git project all I got was `Skipped patch`.

Using `git init <TEMP_PROJECT_FOLDER>` allowed the patch to be applied although this may not be necessary for you.

Other tips:

- `--directory` resulted in `error: invalid path` because PowerShell's tolerance of `/` in paths is only superficial (I gather).  So **need to change current working directory**.
- `--verbose` helps but isn't comprehensive
- Other options from @Moerwald: `--ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace --whitespace=nowarn`

Answer (score -1):

Is `git apply` an alternative? If so, try:

```
  invoke-expression "git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace --whitespace=no warn file.patch
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Resulted in `error: invalid path` when trying to use `--directory`.  Avoiding `--directory` by setting current directory doesn't help; each patches get message `Skipped patch`.  My IDE can apply patch just fine however.  See also [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386491/git-apply-skips-patches)