# How can I apply a diff created with git diff --relative?

Tags: git

Given a git repository with the following file structure:

```
<repo root>
  foo
    example.md
```

I have committed `example.md` with the contents `Hello world`. If I navigate to the `foo` directory and make a change to `example.md`, I can generate a relative diff with `git diff --relative > d.diff` with the contents:

```
diff --git a/example.md b/example.md
index 802992c..fb5067b 100644
--- a/example.md
+++ b/example.md
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Hello world
+Hello again
```

If I now checkout `example.md` to undo the change, then try to apply the diff with `git apply d.diff` (still in the `foo` directory), the command exits silently and no changes are applied. How can I apply this relative diff, or generate a relative diff in such a way that it can be applied?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer the question of why `git apply` doesn't work here, but based on the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42386570/1340041 I've found a workaround: `patch -p1 < d.diff`